# Skipping incompatible libpcap.so - cross compilation

Tags: c++, c, linker, libpcap

I am trying to link libpcap to my project, but I achive an error

```
skipping incompatible /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcap.so when searching for -lpcap
```

I'm using cross compiler arm linux gcc.

I've found some topics with related problems but i haven't found solution for me.
How to link this lib correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to do? To build an arm software on a i386 computer?

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide libpcap.so built for arm..

You can check for architecture by calling:

```
file libpcap.so
```

Output:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.1.5.3: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, **x86-64**, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=916b377cfe593106dc0b054d63bc4ed0af4ad269, stripped

You can [crosscompile](https://emreboy.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/cross-compile-libpcap-source-code/) the pcap lib from [here](http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.7.4.tar.gz)

Comment: I try to cross compile it but when I use {CC=arm-linux-gcc ac_cv_linux_vers=2 ./configure --host=arm-linux --with-pcap=linux} I get: configure: error: in '/.../libpcap-1.7.4 and C compiler cannot create executables

Comment: @kmbm in configure log check what C compiler is used... maybe you should add a - to --host=arm-linux... further you should also add build option so that configure not tries to execute binary files... if none of this worked add --with-cc=... and with-ld=... to configure command.

Comment: @kmbm  agree with mhk .. you need to provide correct name of your gcc binary for arm - not just copy pasting the tutorial I linked..

Comment: You are, right. I have changed arm-linux-gcc to arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc and it works. But I have problem with 'make'. I get an error './pcap-linux.c:254:14: conflicting types for socklen_t       /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/unistd.h:275:21: note previous declaration of 'socklen_t' was here       I didn't modify any files.